# Apache rewrite all URL's to https with www + a few exceptions

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect

I've tried all the answers to similar stack questions and nothing has worked. I need to redirect all to https://www except for example.com/blogs/* and example.com/page-name.

I currently have this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

which redirects everything except for https://example.com, it will NOT add the www.

You can see for yourself at https://moblized.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.moblized.com/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^moblized.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.moblized.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} blogs 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://moblized.com/blogs/$1 [R,L]

# Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

# $Id: .htaccess,v 1.90.2.4 2009/12/07 12:00:40 goba Exp $

AddHandler php5-script .php
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I hope I understood you correctly. You want:

- redirect from `example.com` to `www.example.com` (except /blogs/ and /page-name)
- redirect all pages to HTTPS (except /blogs/ and /page-name)
- based on your current .htaccess under `/page-name` you mean `/favicon.ico`

Here are the rules for the above requirements -- put them into your .htaccess:

```
# activate rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# don't touch favicon.ico (always accept as is regardless of the domain or protocol)
RewriteRule ^favicon.ico$ - [L]
# don't touch /index.php (usually means already overwritten URL)
# otherwise we may enter into a loop
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# ensure trailing slash is present for /blogs -> /blogs/
RewriteRule ^blogs$ http://mobilized.com/blogs/ [R=301,QSA,L]
# /blogs/ should only be accessible via http://example.com/blogs/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^moblized\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^blogs/(.*)$ http://mobilized.com/blogs/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^moblized\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^blogs/(.*)$ http://mobilized.com/blogs/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/.* - [L]

# redirect to www.example.com if necessary
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^moblized\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/client-ipad-contest
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.moblized.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]

# redirect to HTTPS if not there already
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/client-ipad-contest
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.moblized.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]

# Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

BTW, browser most likely will show "Untrusted Certificate" warning if your customer go to `https://example.com`. This is because HTTPS session has to be fully established first before the request starts processing by Apache's rewrite module.

If that is problem -- then consider buying another SSL certificate (or from another vendor) which will cover both `example.com` and `www.example.com` (GoDaddy does this for sure) or get wildcard certificate which will cover all subdomains -- `*.example.com` (but this most likely will be much more expensive).

---

**UPDATE:** After simulating your requirements locally (sorry, I have no SSL with working Apache, so I have replaced it (in my testing) with different kind of rule/domain name) I have revised and updated the rules.

I've tested these rules locally (all pages are very simple, just include 1 image & css and a bit of text) -- everything looking good. Let me know if something does not work.

Comment: Ah okay, that untrusted rect was a part of why it wasn't working before. This worked perfectly, thanks so much. LazyOne doesn't fit you very well haha

Comment: Whoa on further testing this causes a lot of problems. Stylesheet doesn't load on the blog pages and the main pages do no redirect to SSL

Comment: @Jordan Main page? Can you please give **EXACT** url of what does not work. Regarding blogs -- my mistake -- please change `/blog/` to `/blogs/` (I forgot to type `s`)

Comment: Any page that is supposed to be https is not being redirected to https from http. http://moblized.com -- it's live right now

Comment: @Jordan Can you please show your FULL current .htaccess file. I'm trying to figure out what may be wrong .. but can't really see anything tight now (but I do see that site is not working properly)

Comment: Accidentally added it to your answer but it's being buggy and won't let me re-edit it

Comment: @Jordan Better add it to your original question -- in this case you will be able to delete it when not required any more.

Comment: Added it to the question. Sorry I thought you left it in your answer for now

Comment: @Jordan Based on your .htaccess I have checked & revised the rules. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: @Jordan Let me know if you want `/blogs/` to be always accessible in this way: `http://domain.com/blogs/`. And if customer types `http://www.domain.com/blogs/` he will be redirected to the "proper" URL.

Comment: Actually `/page-title` should be `/client-ipad-contest`. Yes I would like for that blog redirect to be in place as well. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: I tried including `RewriteRule ^client-ipad-contest$ - [L]` but that messes up the file name rules at the bottom and displays the index instead

Comment: @Jordan So `client-ipad-contest` should not be affected with any redirects (regardless of HTTPS or domain name), right? (I will make it work properly instead of showing notfound/index page)

Comment: @Jordan Updated my answer with revised rules. `/blogs/` should ONLY be accessible via `http://example.com/blogs/`. If requested page is `/client-ipad-contest` then no redirects to is involved (URL stays the same).

Comment: Still having problems with client-ipad-contest - it redirects to this: `https://www.moblized.com/index.php?q=client-ipad-contest` see for yourself at http://moblized.com/client-ipad-contest

Comment: @Jordan 1) Hmm ... try replacing `!^/client-ipad-contest` by `!=/client-ipad-contest` 2) The current .htaccess version -- is it still your version or the one that I have provided? If it is possible -- can you leave my version -- at least I could see where it tries to redirect (especially if you have more problems than just client-ipad-contest)

Comment: Your version is live. That edit didn't fix it unfortunately. Click the link in my above comment to see the redirect. That page is the only one giving me problems

Comment: @Jordan Yeah, I see -- the reason is -- when rule hits `/index.php` (the last rule) it, for some strange and unknown for me yet reason, goes to another loop .. and on that loop it already not `/client-ipad-contest` but `/index.php?q=client-ipad-contest` and therefore it get's redirected to HTTPS as you see it right now. Let me dig it a bit dipper -- I have some ideas I need to try ...

Comment: @Jordan Just updated -- I have added the rule just for `/index.php` -- it will exit straight away. This means that IF somebody requests this file directly (e.g. `http://domain.com/index.php`) it will NOT be redirected to HTTPS. That is the only way I see working, otherwise it goes into another loop after each redirect. No redirects = no loops.

Comment: YES it works! Oh man I cannot thank you enough. If you ever need some help with design elements or anything with Photoshop, let me know.

Comment: @Jordan np - I have spent quite a bit of time on this but at the same time I have learned about "rewriting going into loops". I consider it was worth it. Ta